# Difference between const vector and const iterator

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

If I am passing a vector to a function as reference and I want the function should not modify the vector, what is better - using `const vector<>` or using `vector::const_iterator`?

For example, I am traversing through a vector passed from `main()` to `foo()`.

```
void foo (const vector<int> &v1) {
vector<int>::const_iterator m;

for(m=v1.begin();m1!=v1.end();++m1)
//loop body

}
```

And `main()` is

```
int main() {
vector<int> v11={0,1,2,3,4};
foo(v11);
}
```

In this case, `v1` should be `const` or `m` should be `const_iterator`?

Comment: `v1` should be `const` and `m` should be `auto`.

Comment: Why `v1` should be `const`? And `C++11` does provide `auto` keyword. But specifying explicit type shouldn't be faster and better in performance as compared to `auto`?

Comment: @edf233: no, `auto` is purely syntactic sugar. It does not have any negative performance impact.

Comment: "Why v1 should be const?" Because your function does not have intention to modify it and that the way to write error free programs to show it. "But specifying explicit type shouldn't be faster and better in performance as compared to auto?" it may in some rare cases when type on the left is different that on the right. But usually you do not want that.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to prevent `foo` from modifying its argument, then the argument should be taken as `const`. You won't be able to obtain a non-`const` iterator from a `const` reference to an `std::vector`, as the non-`const` qualified version of `std::vector::begin` is not accessible.

Additionally, we have a clean way to express iteration over a range in C++11: range-`for` loops.

```
void foo(const vector<int> &v1) 
{
    for(const auto& x : v1) { /* use x */ }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> In this case, v1 should be const or m should be const_iterator?

If you decide to pass an iterator, you'll need to pass two arguments -- the start and the end. Otherwise, you won't be able figure out when to stop the iteration.

The following does not work.

```
void foo (vector<int>::const_iterator start) {
   // for(m=v1.begin();m1!=v1.end();++m1)
   for ( auto m1 = start; m1 != v1.end(); ++m1 ) // There is no way to compute v1.end().

   //loop body
}
```

The following works.

```
void foo (vector<int>::const_iterator start, vector<int>::const_iterator end) {
   for (  auto m1 = start; m1 != end; ++m1 )
   //loop body
}
```

which means, you will need to call the function with:

```
foo(v11.begin(), v11.end());
```

Unless there is a need to support iterating with a subset of the contents of the vector, there is no need to support this version of `foo`.

On the other hand, you may support both without too much trouble.

```
void foo (vector<int>::const_iterator start, vector<int>::const_iterator end) {
   for (  auto m1 = start; m1 != end; ++m1 )
   //loop body
}

void foo (vector<int>::const& v) {
   foo(v.begin(), v.end());
}
```

That allows you use

```
vector<int> v11={0,1,2,3,4};
foo(v11); // Do something for all the elements of v11.
foo(v11.begin(), v11.begin()+2); // Do the same thing only for the first two elements of v11.
```